# canot complete autorize APIs in auth2 playground

Tags: oauth2-playground

affter i funished to configure configure consent screen and then i moved to the auth2 playground and i insert authorize APIs https://mail.google.com/ it askes me to to enter the site throu my goole account i get  noticed that the confermaition ist comlete and i gt this 403 error
בקשת פרטים: access_type=offline response_type=code redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground prompt=consent client_id=95979685927-0p0kl0nsekdtiit7qpjhelhk2p33dmgj.apps.googleusercontent.com scope=https://mail.google.com why is that and how can i fix it?